# HTML/CSS, have an element with top and bottom margin (or padding), only if element content have a height > 0

Tags: html, css, height, margin, padding

I need to have an element with top and bottom margin (or padding), only if the elements content has a height.

The element in question always has some content inserted via javascript (it's an ad container), and if there is an adblocker present, or no ad available to show, I don't want to display anything at all for the visitor. Just as if there was nothing there. Although, if there is an ad, I need to have some margin/padding above and below it.

The main issue is that the adserver software always inserts a beacon to the container, so something like `ins:empty { display: none }` does only work with adblockers (since it blocks the beacon as well), but not if there is no ad available (the beacon will then be inserted anyway to register a blank view).

A solution would be if there was a way to apply styling to a elements parent, but from what I know, thats not possible.

I want to use CSS for this if possible, and not involve any javascript.

Thanks

```
<ins>
    **if there is a banner, that code will be inserted here**
    <div class="beacon"><img ...></div>
</ins>

ins {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;

    &::before {
        content: '';
        height: 15px;
        display: block;
    }

    &::after {
        content: '';
        height: 15px;
        display: block;
    }
}

ins:empty {
    display: none;
}
```

Above is how I've done so far (there is a reason I'm using before and after, and not simply padding, but that part is irrelevant for this question so I've removed it). This works with adblocker, but not with empty ads.

Comment: Is there any code you've have already tried?

Comment: I've edited the first post and included what I've tried so far. Thanks.